# how to manipulate angular-ui-date with bower

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, css, jquery-ui-datepicker

This is my console error:

[image: This is my console error !]

Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.date' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about what questions (not) to ask and how to ask good questions. Please provide the code that allows to reproduce the issue, shows what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: I am fairly new to angular and using it with JSON api files.

Comment: Im trying to modify my design (html page ) , I had this error while executing the page ;

Comment: In this case it's even more important that you post what you tried because it's much harder to predict what beginners might do ;-) I have not the slightest idea what your question is about. I have a slight suspicion that it's not even about Angular2 as the added tag suggests but about Angular1.

Comment: its about angular1.5 ;

Comment: Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ui.date due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ui.date' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$injector/nomod?p0=ui.date
    at http://localhost:8090/bower_components/angular/angular.js:68:12
    at http://localhost:8090/bower_components/angular/angular.js:2034:17
    at ensure

Comment: I want to add the angular-ui-date to the bower Json !  have u any idea about that !

Comment: Then add the angularjs tag instead the angular2 tag. You can't expect an answer by dropping some fragments of something.

Comment: its okkay ;-) !! am asking about how to install a new component with bower     !! and match it the bower.json already existing  ! I hope u can understand me !

Comment: Maybe someone else. I don't know about Angular1 or bower, only Angular2.

Comment: thank u for ur time :D